# Backsweetening cider and carbonation drops

Tags: bottling, carbonation, cider

I just completed my first batch of hard cider. I was told to backsweeten it, which I did with Erythritol to taste about 3 weeks ago. then to put carbonation drops in each bottle before adding the backsweetened cider. I'm using Grolsch bottles. Was I wrong to both backsweeten and add carbonation drops?? Did I ruin one gallon of cider?

Comment: Backsweeten is a nonsense word. I'm not sure where it comes from. Nobody in the wine industry uses it. I guess the correct way to say this is simply to "add sweetness" because you aren't putting sweetness back into the cider. Sorry a pet peeve of mine...

Answer (score 1):

Erythritol is non fermentable. You'll be fine.